# Right way to extend spring beans

Tags: spring

Suppose I have a custom starter that has the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
class StarterConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(BaseBean.class)
    BaseBean getBean() {return new BaseBean()}
}
```

And in my application which utilized the starter, I have the following:

```
@Component
class AppBean extends BaseBean {
}
```

I noticed both beans get instantiated. Those code that previously autowired to refer to BaseBean are now automatically looking at AppBean. When I cross-checked the name of BaseBean(getBean) with all the application beans (appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) it is no longer there. Only AppBean is available. Which is a nice way of extending or overriding bean logic.

But is this the right way to extend the logic of a bean? Especially, when I noticed that BaseBean is instantiated but never destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have multiple Beans of the same type or simultaneously have Beans extending each other, you need to give them a "name" (Qualifier) using the annotation @Qualifier both on the Bean definition and on the Autowired member.

Read about it here: [Spring Bean Qualifiers](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation)